# What does "She is tall for her age" mean?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I read the following sentence

> She is tall for her age.

Now I'm greatly confused about its meaning. Does it mean "*she would have as long age as she is tall*" (perhaps showing prediction) 
Or "*she is as tall as her age*"

Which meaning is correct or is there a third meaning?

Comment: In this context, "for her age" means the same as "compared with other people of her own age".

Comment: It's also worth emphasizing that the expression "tall for [one's] age" applies only to non-adults. You would never refer to a 45-year-old as "tall for her age"—even if, objectively, she is.

Comment: @SvenYargs but you can say of a woman that *She looks good for her age*; and of a man, *He looks fits/young for his age*.

Comment: Yes - the "for his/her age" is based on a presumption of a changing situation with age.  Since after youth, height is fixed with age but health is not, you have the reversal. Nobody says a child "looks good for her age"

Comment: It's also worth noting that it's typically used not in comparison to other people of the same age but rather other women of that age.

Comment: Thank you. I like this question. (I came across this question when I searched the meaning of "for her age" about Charlotte Aulin on google web.

Answer (score 6):

> She is tall for her age

This means that she is noticeably taller than the average height of girls her age.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same kind of "for" as you find in:

- "It's warm for December" - the temperature is not high in an *absolute* sense, but is high *within the range* of temperature that one might expect to find in December.
- "That's a good effort for a beginner" - the result is not particularly good in an *absolute* sense, but is good *within the range* of results that one might expect from a beginner
- "She is tall for her age" - she is not tall in an *absolute* sense, but *within the range* of heights of people her age, she is at the tall end.

This is usage #11 within [Wiktionary: for - Preposition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for#Preposition)